# How to operate elementwise on a matrix of type scipy.sparse.csr_matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, operation

In numpy if you want to calculate the sinus of each entry of a matrix (elementise) then

```
a = numpy.arange(0,27,3).reshape(3,3)
numpy.sin(a)
```

will get the job done! If you want the power let's say to 2 of each entry

```
a**2
```

will do it.

But if you have a sparse matrix things seem more difficult. At least I haven't figured a way to do that besides iterating over each entry of a lil_matrix format and operate on it.

I've found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247775/how-to-elementwise-multiply-a-scipy-sparse-matrix-by-a-broadcasted-dense-1d-arra) and tried to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357645/641514) but I was not succesful.

The Goal is to calculate elementwise the squareroot (or the power to 1/2) of a scipy.sparse matrix of CSR format.

What would you suggest?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Element-wise power of scipy.sparse matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431557/element-wise-power-of-scipy-sparse-matrix)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following trick works for any operation which maps zero to zero, and only for those operations, because it only touches the non-zero elements. I.e., it will work for `sin` and `sqrt` but not for `cos`.

Let `X` be some CSR matrix...

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> X = csr_matrix(np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5), dtype=np.float)
>>> X.A
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

The non-zero elements' values are `X.data`:

```
>>> X.data
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
```

which you can update in-place:

```
>>> X.data[:] = np.sqrt(X.data)
>>> X.A
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.41421356,  1.73205081,  2.        ],
       [ 2.23606798,  2.44948974,  2.64575131,  2.82842712,  3.        ]])
```

**Update** In recent versions of SciPy, you can do things like `X.sqrt()` where `X` is a sparse matrix to get a new copy with the square roots of elements in `X`.

Comment: @Aufwind: I got so sick and tired of operating on `.data` that I submitted a [patch](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/138) to Scipy implementing `sqrt`, `sin` and `tan` on CSR and CSC matrices.

Comment: This is great, I am sure many people will be verythankful! :-)

Comment: There is a reason not to support these operations on matrices directly; exponentiation of a matrix already has a standard and quite different meaning from the elementwise one proposed here. Personally, I think sparse matrices ought to respect linear algebra semantics by default; if what you really want is a sparse array, then maybe there should be a subclass for that, analogous with their dense counterparts.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn SciPy sparse matrices effectively follow linear algebra conventions, which is a pain because NumPy arrays don't. SciPy should really have sparse *arrays*, but every attempt to implement them so far has failed.

Comment: Apparently not, as per the latest scipy, since sparse.sqrt is an elementwise squareroot. Personally, ive often used sparse matrices, and never had a need for sparse arrays. So I am ok with sparse matrices (mostly) acting as matrices. The base class is called spmatrix; not sparray. That said, an sparray could be neat; but then youd also want an sp-nd-array generalization, and its not directly clear how to go forward with that. But as for low hanging fruit, I think spmatrix should be castable to a 2d sparray, in order for array semantics to be enabled, and spmatrix should have pure LA semantics.

Comment: Is there any way to access the index of elements with this? That is, performing `A[i,j] = f(A[i,j], i, j)` as opposed to `A[i,j] = f(A[i,j])`?