# sqrt for element-wise sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, sqrt

I have a sparse matrix:

```
from scipy import sparse
a = sparse.diags([1,4,9],[-1,0,1],shape =(10,10),format ="csr")
```

I want to take the square root of each of the elements in the sparse matrix 
I look up on the internet and it says I can use numpy.sqrt() to implement this. 
But error occurs:

```
  b = numpy.sqrt(a)
  AttributeError: sqrt
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I think your question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906506/how-to-operate-elementwise-on-a-matrix-of-type-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix): you can use `a.sqrt()` or act on `a.data` for anything that doesn't have a native hook.

Comment: @DSM: `a.sqrt()` should be an answer.

Comment: @DSM  thanks. a.sqrt() works. Just need to make sure that the right version of scipy is installed.

Comment: @DSM What if I want to take power of two(square) of each of the elements in a sparse matrix? Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: @DSM for square, I just found out a method. a.multiply(a) works.I can use it as a substitute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caveat, this will create a resulting numpy ndarray instead of a sparse csr array.

```
from scipy import sparse
a = sparse.diags([1,4,9],[-1,0,1],shape =(10,10),format ="csr")

numpy.sqrt(a.data)
```

As far as I can tell most of the other ufunc operations (sin, cos, ... ) do have sparse ufuncs except for sqrt, don't know the reason why. See this issue: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/208

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a sparse matrix (which you almost certainly do!) you can apply the function to `a.data` instead.

```
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = sparse.diags([1,4,9],[-1,0,1],shape =(10,10),format ="csr")
>>> a.data = np.sqrt(a.data)
>>> a
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 28 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Credit to [DSM's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070690/sqrt-for-element-wise-sparse-matrix#comment31688015_21070690) for this answer.